Resultado de algoritmo para prueba TECNICA
Estoy intentando resolver el siguiente algoritmo para una propuesta laboral, y consigo tener el resultado que solicitan en las 10 primeras iteraciones, pero luego al querer aplicarlo para 100 iteraciones y sacar el valor de la variable D modulo 10000000000 (ultimos 10 digitos) el resultado ya me arroja otro resultado completamente distinto: Dejo el acertijo a continuacion para saber si alguien resolvio algo similar alguna vez:
¿Cuál sería el resultado de ejecutar el siguiente pseudocódigo? teniendo en cuenta que el dispositivo dispone de los recursos necesarios para finalizar su ejecución. Los puntos a continuación son para indentación.
función solucionarRompecabezas(N) {
.var_A = 1
.var_B = 1
.var_C = 1
.var_D = 1

.para i en el rango de 1 a N {
..resultado = 3 * var_D + 1 * var_C + 4 * var_B + 1 * var_A
..var_A = var_B
..var_B = var_C
..var_C = var_D
..var_D = resultado
.}

.devolver var_D % 10000000000 // últimos 10 dígitos de var_D
}

mostrar solucionarRompecabezas(10)
mostrar solucionarRompecabezas(100)
mostrar solucionarRompecabezas(pot(2023, 100)) // 2023 elevado a la 100

Salida
902441
8042318513
??

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! No entiendo siquiera como resolves eso o sea cual es el problema??? quien te dice que tu resultado esta mal?? como lo ejecutas???

8042318513 te confirmo que ese resultado es correcto

Hola Emanuel, bienvenido... 2023 elevado a la 100... puede que este muy dormido, pero no creo que tengas una computadora capaz de manejar ese número.

Muchas gracias por las respuestas Yussef y Marce, pude lograr resolverlo buscando un poco de informacion y entendiendo mas en profundidas el problema a resolver.
Agradezco su ayuda y la paciencia, es mi primer contacto con esta comunidad! Saludos cordiales!

Tu comentario aca no sirve para absolutamente nada... nadie lo va a leer... esto no es una red social, aprende a usar el sitio...

Yo puedo aprender a utilizar el sitio. Estoy dando mis primeros pasos y probablemente lo haga. Por tu parte dudo que aprendas de empatía, a cómo responder y tratar a la gente. Saludos

Traducido a Python:
def solucionarRompecabezas(N):
    var_A = 1
    var_B = 1
    var_C = 1
    var_D = 1

    for i in range(1, N + 1):
        resultado = 3 * var_D + 1 * var_C + 4 * var_B + 1 * var_A
        var_A = var_B
        var_B = var_C
        var_C = var_D
        var_D = resultado


    return var_D % 10000000000


print(solucionarRompecabezas(10))
print(solucionarRompecabezas(100))
#print(solucionarRompecabezas(2023 ** 100))

Observaciones:

El rango del for. En Python, range(1, N) produce 1, 2, ... N - 1. Si quieres llegar hasta N, tienes que sumarle 1 al límite superior: range(1, N + 1). Siempre hay que revisar si el rango incluye o no el valor final, según que lenguaje o pseudolenguaje estás usando.

2023 ** 100 es un número bien grande y ahí el programa se va a quedar pegado un largooooo tiempo.


El código produce resultados
902441
8042318513


Muchas gracias por tu respuesta!

Me parece que tu problema se produce al estar utilizando números excesivamente grandes.
Debes recordar que lo importante son los 10 últimos números, por lo que desde el digito 11 hacia la izquierda no son relevantes y lo puedes truncar. Esto gracias a que todas las operaciones que realizas son sumas y multiplicaciones.
Por ejemplo: Para simplificar diremos que nos interesa el último número de la operación (12312 + 47456) * 18
El resultado de la operación es 1075824
En realidad, solo debemos preocuparnos del primer digito (el más de la derecha)
(2+6) * 8 = 64

El último digito es 4

Para tu caso son los 10 últimos números, entonces realizas la operación modulo en cada iteración:
función solucionarRompecabezas(N) {
.var_A = 1
.var_B = 1
.var_C = 1
.var_D = 1

.para i en el rango de 1 a N {
..resultado = 3 * var_D + 1 * var_C + 4 * var_B + 1 * var_A
..var_A = var_B
..var_B = var_C
..var_C = var_D
..var_D = resultado  % 10000000000 // Aquí recortamos el número
.}

.devolver var_D % 10000000000 // últimos 10 dígitos de var_D
}

mostrar solucionarRompecabezas(10)
mostrar solucionarRompecabezas(100)
mostrar solucionarRompecabezas(pot(2023, 100)) // 2023 elevado a la 100

